# Bootstrap input-group-addon durandal knockout validation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, knockout.js, durandal

I've got a field to validate and knockout handles the validation of this element.
Next I've got an input-group-addon which is getting out of bounds when the validation of knockout kicks in. I've been trying to look for a fix but I cannot find another that solves this.

The issue:

[image: The issue]

The code itself is pretty straightforward to be honest:

```html
<div class="form-group" data-bind="validationElement: emailRepeated">
  <label for="emailRepeated" data-bind="text: translate('EmailConfirm')">[Confirm your Email Address]</label>
  <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailRepeated" data-bind="value: emailRepeated" >
  </div>
</div>
```

My knockout just has the extender like so:

```
self.emailRepeated.extend({ required: true, email: true, equal: self.email });
```

Anyone got any idea how I can keep the input addon to stay together with the input?

**EDIT:**
Result HTML after validation:

```html
<div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
     <input type="email" class="form-control has-error" id="emailRepeated" data-bind="value: emailRepeated" title="This is not a proper email address" data-orig-title="">

     <span class="help-block" style="">This is not a proper email address</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the **errorClass** [configuration option](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration) to setup your own css class. Then its a matter of proper floating I guess to get your desired effect.

OK I think I found a solution. Try adding following CSS

```css
.input-group .validationMessage {
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: bottom;
}
```

That will format it as a new row (caption) of your table-style and position it at the bottom

[image]

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfLjdrks/) for demonstration purposes

Update: [second version](http://jsfiddle.net/zfLjdrks/1/) of the fiddle

Comment: Is there no way to get the bootstrap stuff working? I found that as long as it's custom validation you can basically use jquery validation to position the errormessage box. This however is now not possible to use since I'm using durandal and for some reason he cannot access `self` inside of the validation method. Any other suggestions?

Comment: could you maybe create a fiddle of your problem. Knockout itself should be enough because I don't suspect Durandal to create any problems here.

Comment: I still get the same output, the input group breaks with the error message. I guess this means overwriting the standard validation? This I would like to avoid at all costs to be honest.

Comment: I've attached the result from the fiddle. So isn't this what you were expecting? We are not overwriting anything, just adding an css clause for the input-group validationmessage. Take a look at the fiddle

Comment: I did look at the fiddle and am finding it quite weird that this works with you and not with me. Also I don't have the "validationMessage" class on validation but rather the "help-block" class is added on the span. So I tried adding your css there but still it gives me the same visual output.

Comment: well that is more than strange ... I'm using latest Chrome, what browser are you on? IE 11 works as well. Maybe just try creating an empty project for yourself with only the necessary code and see if it works. Can't understand where that help-block comes from.

Comment: I believe the help-block is coming from bootstrap itself, hereby overwriting the knockout validation message class. I am using IE10 (don't ask). Though I did also test on chrome to no success...

Comment: Are you refering to the fiddle or your project?

Comment: Can you update your question and paste the resulting HTML with the message visible? Above doesnt say anything about that helpblock. Additionally your validation.init config if set.

Comment: Updated the question as requested. I really want to get this working.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle (in answer) and added your new html ... by just stating the new css class instead old one it works as expected. So I guess if that doesn't help there is some other CSS that is breaking your display. Try disabling it step-wise to see what causes the issue

Comment: It works! Thank you. Apparently the CSS file I was using was not included properly so your fiddle was correct. Thank you so much for the help! Much appreciated!

Comment: Don't even bother with css.  Implement kengineer's solution below. Pure javascript fix.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is a little late but I had the same problem and came up with a different solution. What I do is override the ko.validation.insertValidationMessage function to look to see if the element is part of an input-group. If so, I have the message insert after the input-group parent element instead. This works whether the input-group-addon is on the left or right.

```
var insertValidationMessage = ko.validation.insertValidationMessage;

ko.validation.insertValidationMessage = function (element) {
    if ($(element.parentElement).hasClass('input-group')) {
        return insertValidationMessage(element.parentElement);
    }
    return insertValidationMessage(element);
}
```

Here's it working in js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kengineer/zfLjdrks/6/

Comment: This solution is beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `input-group-addon` on the right of the input, the answer of zewa666 is not working.

In this case, you can use absolute positioning. Something like this:

```
.input-group .help-block {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 28px;
}

.form-group.has-error {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```